# Can't view prediction result with built model in R

Tags: r, h2o

I'm a beginner with R, and just had some trouble with the prediction function.
I built a Random Forest model with `h2o`, where the `y` is 0/1(buy/no buy).
 Then, I tried to use the `predict()` function to apply the model to a new dataset
eg: `pre=predict(rf,test_data)`

I can see the summary of my prediction result like below:

```
> summary(pre)
   predict p0               p1                 
   0:998   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :5.601e-05  
   1: 97   1st Qu.:0.9989   1st Qu.:5.601e-05  
           Median :0.9989   Median :5.601e-05  
           Mean   :0.9150   Mean   :8.498e-02  
           3rd Qu.:0.9989   3rd Qu.:5.601e-05  
           Max.   :0.9999   Max.   :1.000e+00
```

But, I couldn't `View()` my prediction result as a list. Here is what I got when using `View(pre)`:

[image]

Ultimately, I'd like to know which row has been predicted as 1(buy), which row has been predicted as 0(no buy). Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?
thanks a lot!

Comment: You just need to `print(pre)` to see the prediction result for each row.

Comment: use `pre_df <- as.data.frame(pre)` to get it in R

Comment: hi s.brunel, thanks a lot! this works!

Answer (score 0):

@s.brunel has the right answer. Keep in mind when writing routines that with binary predictions it will return three variables. Whereas when predicting a continuous variable you get a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

posting the answer to make it easier to find.

If you want to use R functions on an H2OFrame you will first need to convert that H2OFrame to an R frame and you can do that as follows for your particular case:

```
pre_df <- as.data.frame(pre)
```

Please also note that some H2O functions use the same naming convention as R functions, so while you may think the `summary()` function was an R function it was actually the H2O `summary()` function which does the same thing as the R function but for an H2OFrame.